# Requery/Empty Subform Linked to Unbound text box

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

How do I requery a subform linked to an unbound control on the main form? This unbound control contains the PK for the record they lookup.  Since I'm not interested in binding the main form to a table I need to do it via VBA.

[ClosedLoans] = main form, unbound

[ClosedLoanNote] = sub form, bound to SS table

None of these have worked:

```
[Forms]![ClosedLoans]![ClosedLoanNote].Form.Requery
[Forms]![ClosedLoans]![ClosedLoanNote].Requery
Me!ClosedLoanNote.Form.Requer
Me![ClosedLoans]!Form.Requery
Me.Refresh 'On the main form
Me.Requery 'On the main form
```

Comment: `[Forms]![ClosedLoans]![ClosedLoanNote].Form.Requery` this should work perfectly. You can also try `Me.ClosedLoanNote.Form.Requery`.

Answer (score 1):

Ah this one worked finally... for some reason it wasn't but now is.  That can't be good.  I will rethink the need to rebuild the form based off of the SS table to make sure I don't frankenstein this any more than I have to.

[Forms]![ClosedLoans]![ClosedLoanNote].Requery